# Correcting Key Errors

Tags: python

I am still learning about dictionaries and I am new to Python, so I do apologize if the wording of my question is incorrect. I am working on a project with the code attached. It works to an extent but if the user is in the great hall and inputs north, I get a key error because you can't go north from the great hall. Is there something I am missing?

```
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}
current_room = 'Great Hall'
directions = 'North', 'South', 'East', 'West'

while True:
    print('You are in the {}'.format(current_room))
    command = input('Which direction would you like to go?')
    if command in directions:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][command]
    elif command == 'Exit':
        print('Thanks for playing!')
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter North, South, East, or West')
```

Comment: How about checking which direction you can go from the current room?

Comment: Such as `if command in rooms[current_room]:`.  That will check if the command is a key in the room's dictionary of directions available.

Comment: Thank you! That was the statement I was missing. I have corrected it and no key errors are appearing.